# Why there is a mismatch of layers in R according to how the plot panel is resized?

Tags: raster, coordinate-system, r, vector-layer

**Background**

In R, I have downloaded two datasets using the following commands (slighlty modificed from https://mgimond.github.io/Spatial/point-pattern-analysis-in-r.html):

```
library(maptools)
z <- gzcon(url("http://colby.edu/~mgimond/Spatial/Data/starbucks.rds"))
location <- readRDS(z)

z <- gzcon(url("http://colby.edu/~mgimond/Spatial/Data/ma.rds"))
citylimits <- readRDS(z)
```

The first is of class SpatialPointsDataframe, while the second is of class SpatialPolygonsDataFrame.
I have also downloaded a SpatialGridDataFrame, which I have converted to a RasterLayer:

```
z <- gzcon(url("http://colby.edu/~mgimond/Spatial/Data/pop_sqmile.rds"))
popdensity <- readRDS(z)
popdensity <-raster::raster(popdensity)
```

**Problem**

Depending on the way in which (in RStudio) I resize the plot panel, it seems that the raster layer doesn't match the rest of the data (see attached images).

**Question**

Is that an RStudio issue, or is it an issue regarding the coordinate system of the layers? As for the latter, I have checked the CRS and the three are listed below (along with other info). I do not understand whether the raster layers' coord.ref exactly matches that of the two other layers. Is what described caused by different coord. ref. embedded in the layers?

popdensity

```
class       : RasterLayer 
dimensions  : 308, 598, 184184  (nrow, ncol, ncell)
resolution  : 500, 500  (x, y)
extent      : 623157.2, 922157.2, 4602709, 4756709  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
coord. ref. : +proj=utm +zone=18 +ellps=GRS80 +towgs84=0,0,0,0,0,0,0 +units=m +no_defs
data source : in memory
names       : band1 
values      : 5.9, 61572.7  (min, max)
```

locations

```
class       : SpatialPointsDataFrame 
features    : 171 
extent      : 648032.3, 917740.7, 4609785, 4748107  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
coord. ref. : +proj=utm +zone=18 +datum=NAD83 +units=m +no_defs +ellps=GRS80 +towgs84=0,0,0
```

citylimits

```
class       : SpatialPolygonsDataFrame 
features    : 1 
extent      : 623157.2, 921923.8, 4602709, 4756659  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
coord. ref. : +proj=utm +zone=18 +datum=NAD83 +units=m +no_defs +ellps=GRS80 +towgs84=0,0,0
variables   : 4
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: Just reissue the plot commands to the new canvas size and everything will be aligned again. This is just a quirk of the graphic device when resized.

Comment: Thanks for your input. My impression was that there was something wrong with the coord. systems. I wish this does not sound as a new question, but why the RasterLayer is actually missing the reference to NAD83 that is featuring the other two layers instead? Is NAD83 equivalent to the "ellps=GRS80" statement featuring the RasterLayer?